# Can I test Apple TV apps on a consumer model?

Tags: appletv

Just a simple question: I’m looking to develop an Apple TV application for the fourth generation Apple TV, and just wondered if any one knew if I can deploy and test home-made apps to a consumer Apple TV model? Or do I need to purchase a special development kit of some sort for this?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/tvos/developer-kit/

Comment: @Tyson “Registration Closed”.

Comment: Good place to start tho... I realized 1 sec too late that was the pre-launch link, but it will lead you to the tvos developer program

Comment: The short answer is yes you test on the same device, but you need to join the developer program to acquire access to the tools you need.

Comment: @Tyson What tools do I need (other than Xcode)? Can I not self-sign test apps on Apple TV like I can iOS apps on my iPhone? I realise I’ll need to join their Program to get the app in the App Store, but can I not still test on my own devices?